# My User Edit Profile is always crashing because of the profile picture on E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue with my profile editing class. It always crashes because of the profile picture code.
The class allows me to make changes on my Profile, which are getting saved in the Firebase Cloud Database. Everything works perfectly fine, but something is wrong with the profile picture. I keep having problems with it.

First I am calling a method witch opens the gallery and loads the picture into the user

```
user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            filechooser();
            //      fileuploader();

            Picasso.get().load(imageurl).into(user);


        }
    });
```

with the methods fileuploader, getExtension, filechooser and onActivityResult

```
// uploads and open gallery on device
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        imageurl = data.getData();
        user.setImageURI(imageurl);

    }

}

private void filechooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


}

private String getExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));
}


private void fileuploader() {
    final StorageReference Ref = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "," + getExtension(imageurl));
    uploadtask = Ref.putFile(imageurl)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                    Toast.makeText(ProfilBearbeiten.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                    Ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            // Got the download URL, so write it to the database
                            userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);

                            documentReference.update("Image", uri.toString());
                        }
                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                    // ...
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
                }


            });
}
```

}
`

Its crasing on the method **getExtension()** whenever I press "bestätigen" which means confirm and send it to the database. The Database saves the changed data, but the app still crashes

```
bestätigen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get Information from Edit Text or fileuploader()
            final String eemail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            final String efullname = fullName.getText().toString();
            final String eort = ort.getText().toString();
            final String einteresssen = interessen.getText().toString();
            final String ebeschreibung = beschreibung.getText().toString();
            final String etelefonnummer = telefonummer.getText().toString();
            final String bild = "";
            final String image = imageurl != null ? imageurl.toString() : null;


            userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);

            //save edited Information in Database

            Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("Benutername", efullname);
            user.put("EMail", eemail);
            user.put("Ort", eort);
            user.put("Interessen", einteresssen);
            user.put("Beschreibung", ebeschreibung);
            user.put("Telefonnummer", etelefonnummer);

            documentReference.set(user);


            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfilBearbeiten.this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            fileuploader();
        }
    });
```

Full Error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.mind.simplelogin, PID: 9013
 java.lang.NullPointerException: url
at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:133)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.getType(ContentResolver.java:716)
        at com.mind.simplelogin.ProfilBearbeiten.getExtension(ProfilBearbeiten.java:190)
        at com.mind.simplelogin.ProfilBearbeiten.fileuploader(ProfilBearbeiten.java:195)
        at com.mind.simplelogin.ProfilBearbeiten.access$100(ProfilBearbeiten.java:57)
        at com.mind.simplelogin.ProfilBearbeiten$2.onClick(ProfilBearbeiten.java:143)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the complete stack trace that follows that `FATAL EXCEPTION` line.

Comment: Please add the _complete_ stack trace; that whole section of red lines.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo the Error appears in the Method  getExtension(Uri uri) in the last line return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));

Comment: You cannot call `fileuploader()` right after `filechooser()` in `onClick()`. That `startActivityForResult()` call does not pause execution of your code, so it immediately continues to `fileuploader()`, but `imageurl` hasn't been set yet. You need to wait until `onActivityResult()` to use `imageurl`. Basically, just move that `fileuploader()` call (and probably the Picasso stuff, as well) to `onActivityResult()`, inside the `if` block.

Comment: thanks it does work like this, but i got a new problem now, because the file keeps uploading, but when i click on "bestätigen" (confirm) the file gets deleted again. Which i just solved, thank you for your help

Comment: @MikeM. Want to post your comment as an answer, so that OP can accept it?